# uWSGI and Flask: keep objects in memory between requests

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

My stack is `uWSGI`, `flask` and `nginx` currently. I have a need to store data between requests (basically I receive push notifications from another service about events to the server and I want to store those events in the server memory, so client can just query server every n milliseconds, to receive latest update).

Normally this would not work, because of many reasons. One is a good deployment requires you to have several processes in `uwsgi` in production (and even maybe several machines to scale this out). But my case is very specific: I'm building a web app for a piece of hardware (You can think of your home router configuration page as a good example). This means no need to scale. I also do not have a database (at least not a traditional one) and probably normally 1-2 clients simultaneously.

if I specify `--processes 1 --threads 4` in `uwsgi`, is this enough to ensure the data is kept in the memory as a single instance? Or do I also need to use `--threads 1`?

I'm also aware that some web servers clear memory randomly from time to time and restart the hosted app. Does `nginx/uwsgi` do that and where can I read about the rules?

I'd also welcome advises on how to design all of this, if there are better ways to handle this. Please note that I do not consider using any persistant storage for this - this does not worth the effort and may be even impossible due to hardware limitations.

Just to clarify: When I'm talking about one instance of data, I'm thinking of my `app.py` executing exactly one time and keeping the instances defined there for as long as the server lives.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need data to persist past a server restart, why not just build a cache object into you application that can do `push` and `pop` operations?

A simple array of objects should suffice, one flask route pushes new data to the array and another can pop the data off the array.

Comment: That is my question, whether can I do that safely and what configuration should I put for this to work. Normally this will not work for the most web servers. This is because web server is allowed to spawn many processes (and cache object from your example is not shared) or kill processes (also for simple clean up) at will

Comment: This is why most of the solutions for caching/scheduling etc. (the stuff that needs some information server side) always work through persistance. Unfortunately, this is not an option for me